# Filter array of objects by array attribute's attribute

Tags: angular

I have an array like this:

```
const array = [
    { id: 1, name: 'a1', props: [
        { name: 'b1', typeId: 1 },
        { name: 'b2', typeId: 1 },
        { name: 'b3', typeId: 5 },
        { name: 'b4', typeId: 5 },
    ] },
    { id: 2, name: 'a2', props: [
        { name: 'c1', typeId: 1 },
        { name: 'c2', typeId: 1 },
        { name: 'c3', typeId: 5 },
    ] },
    { id: 3, name: 'a3', props: [
        { name: 'd1', typeId: 5 },
        { name: 'd2', typeId: 5 },
    ] },
    { id: 4, name: 'a4', props: [
        { name: 'e1', typeId: 1 },
    ] }
];
```

I want to filter this array by prop's typeId attribute. For ex:

If `typeId == 5`, then it should return items that ids are 1, 2, 3 with only props' typeId equals 5. Like this:

```
filteredArray = [
    { id: 1, name: 'a1', props: [
        { name: 'b3', typeId: 5 },
        { name: 'b4', typeId: 5 },
    ] },
    { id: 2, name: 'a2', props: [
        { name: 'c3', typeId: 5 },
    ] },
    { id: 3, name: 'a3', props: [
        { name: 'd1', typeId: 5 },
        { name: 'd2', typeId: 5 },
    ] }
];
```

Or if `typeId == 1`, then it should return items that ids are 1, 2, 4 with only props which typeId equals to 1. Like this:

```
    filteredArray = [
    { id: 1, name: 'a1', props: [
        { name: 'b1', typeId: 1 },
        { name: 'b2', typeId: 1 },
    ] },
    { id: 2, name: 'a2', props: [
        { name: 'c1', typeId: 1 },
        { name: 'c2', typeId: 1 },
    ] },
    { id: 4, name: 'a4', props: [
        { name: 'e1', typeId: 1 },
    ] }
];
```

I wrote something like this, but it doesn't work as intended. It doesn't filter props arrays. Returns an item if it's props array have an item which typeId equals to `typeId`.

```
let typeId = 1;

let filteredArray = array.filter(x => {
  return x.props.some(y => {
    return y.typeId == typeId;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind modifying the input data, you can do it with a `forEach` :

```js
array.forEach(
  (elt) => elt.props = elt.props.filter((subElt) => subElt.typeId === 5)
)
```

Also, you might want to filter elements that have `elt.props` empty :

```js
const result = array.filter(elt => elt.props.length > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map and filter by checking the typeId of the props

```
const array = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'a1',
    props: [{
        name: 'b1',
        typeId: 1
      },
      {
        name: 'b2',
        typeId: 1
      },
      {
        name: 'b3',
        typeId: 5
      },
      {
        name: 'b4',
        typeId: 5
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'a2',
    props: [{
        name: 'c1',
        typeId: 1
      },
      {
        name: 'c2',
        typeId: 1
      },
      {
        name: 'c3',
        typeId: 5
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'a3',
    props: [{
        name: 'd1',
        typeId: 5
      },
      {
        name: 'd2',
        typeId: 5
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'a4',
    props: [{
      name: 'e1',
      typeId: 1
    }]
  }
];

const typeId = 5;

const result = array.map(({
  id,
  name,
  props
}) => ({
  id,
  name,
  props: props.filter(({
    typeId: t
  }) => t === typeId)
})).filter(({
  props
}) => props.length);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `filter` to get the wanted `typeId`s then a `reduce` on the main array to only keep the relevant items.

This method does not modify the original array.

```js
const array = [
    { id: 1, name: 'a1', props: [
        { name: 'b1', typeId: 1 },
        { name: 'b2', typeId: 1 },
        { name: 'b3', typeId: 5 },
        { name: 'b4', typeId: 5 },
    ] },
    { id: 2, name: 'a2', props: [
        { name: 'c1', typeId: 1 },
        { name: 'c2', typeId: 1 },
        { name: 'c3', typeId: 5 },
    ] },
    { id: 3, name: 'a3', props: [
        { name: 'd1', typeId: 5 },
        { name: 'd2', typeId: 5 },
    ] },
    { id: 4, name: 'a4', props: [
        { name: 'e1', typeId: 1 },
    ] }
];
function filterBySubTypeId(baseArray, subprop, subpropValue) {
    return baseArray.reduce((acc, val) => {
    const props = val.props.filter(prop => prop[subprop] === subpropValue); // Keep track of filtered sub-properties
    return props.length > 0 ? [...acc, {...val, props}] : acc; // Return the accumulator or the concatenated accumulator with a modified copy of the item  
  }, [])
}

console.log(filterBySubTypeId(array, 'typeId', 1))
console.log(filterBySubTypeId(array, 'typeId', 5))
console.log(filterBySubTypeId(array, 'typeId', 2)) // []
```